# SFINAE issue with traits detecting division

Tags: c++, c++14, libc++

I have the following traits to detect if two type are divisible, and return the resulting operation type or another `Default` type otherwise:

```
struct default_t { };

// Overloaded template for fallbacks
template <class U, class V>
default_t operator/(U, V);

// If the expression std::declval<U>()/std::declval<V>() is valid,
// gives the return type, otherwize provide Default.
template <class U, class V, class Default>
struct div_type_or {
    using type_ = decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>());
    using type = typename std::conditional<
        std::is_same<type_, default_t>{},
            Default,
            type_>::type;
};

template <class... Args>
using div_type_or_t = typename div_type_or<Args...>::type;
```

This works well with libstdc++, but not with libc++, when I try with a non-divisible `std::chrono::duration` type, e.g.:

```
struct A { };

div_type_or_t<std::chrono::seconds, A, int> b;
```

I get the following error:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:764:81:
>   error: no type named 'type' in
>         'std::__1::common_type'
>                             typename common_type::type>::value>
>                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
>
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:777:7:
>   note: in instantiation of default argument for
>         '__duration_divide_imp >, A>' required here
>       : __duration_divide_imp, _Rep2>
>         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ >
>
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:784:10:
>   note: in instantiation of template class
>         'std::__1::chrono::__duration_divide_result >, A, false>'
>         requested here typename __duration_divide_result, _Rep2>::type
>            ^
>
> test.cpp:16:46: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator/' [with _Rep1 = long
>         long, _Period = std::__1::ratio<1, 1>, *Rep2 = A]
>       using type* = decltype(std::declval() / std::declval());
>                                                ^
>
> test.cpp:24:1: note: in instantiation of template class
>   'div_type_or >, A, D>' requested here using div_type_or_t = typename div_type_or::type; ^
>
> test.cpp:48:19:
>   note: in instantiation of template type alias 'div_type_or_t'
>   requested here
>                     div_type_or_t, D>{}, "");

As I understand this, it is because the following overload of `operator/` for `std::chrono::duration` fails:

```
template< class Rep1, class Period, class Rep2 >
duration<typename std::common_type<Rep1,Rep2>::type, Period>
    constexpr operator/( const duration<Rep1, Period>& d,
                         const Rep2& s );
```

I thought that since the `std::common_type` is part of the function signature, this would allow SFINAE to work and use my custom overload of `operator/` and thus deduce `default_t`, but apparently this does not work...

Since this works with libstdc++, I just wanted to know if there was an issue with my code (maybe I did not understand the way SFINAE would work in this case) or if this was a libc++ bug?

Comment: Being part of the function signature isn't the sole requirement to allow SFINAE to work anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In libc++, we have:

```
template <class _Duration, class _Rep, bool = __is_duration<_Rep>::value>
struct __duration_divide_result
{
};

template <class _Duration, class _Rep2,
    bool = is_convertible<_Rep2,
                          typename common_type<typename _Duration::rep, _Rep2>::type>::value>
struct __duration_divide_imp
{
};

template <class _Rep1, class _Period, class _Rep2>
struct __duration_divide_imp<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2, true>
{
    typedef duration<typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type, _Period> type;
};

template <class _Rep1, class _Period, class _Rep2>
struct __duration_divide_result<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2, false>
    : __duration_divide_imp<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2>
{
};

template <class _Rep1, class _Period, class _Rep2>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR
typename __duration_divide_result<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2>::type
operator/(const duration<_Rep1, _Period>& __d, const _Rep2& __s)
{
    typedef typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type _Cr;
    typedef duration<_Cr, _Period> _Cd;
    return _Cd(_Cd(__d).count() / static_cast<_Cr>(__s));
}
```

So instead of `std::common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type`,
they use `__duration_divide_result<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2 /*, false*/>`,
which instantiates `__duration_divide_imp<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2
/*, is_convertible<_Rep2, typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type>::value*/>`

That usage is an hard error.

I would say that implementation in libc++ is incorrect in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think there is an easy way to fix this in a generic way or should I try to specialise my trait for `std::chrono::duration`?

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds / A` is currently not SFINAE friendly in libc++. as workaround, you might indeed add `default_t operator/(std::chrono::seconds, A);`.